# Trying to get the index firebase database according the state value

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update the firebase database based on the changes of state.
I want everytime i clicked submit, the database is updated based on the index location of data on database.

```
onSubmit = () => {
  const pkp = [...this.state.pkp];
  const value = this.state.selectedOption2.value;
  const index = pkp.indexOf({ value });

  firebaseApp
    .database()
    .ref(`/${index}`)
    .update({ pkp });
};
```

Here my database structure
[Here my firebase database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oByrw.jpg)

I tried to console the variable one by one, and the result is correct, except 
    const index = pkp.indexOf({ value });
the result is -1 , whenever i changed the state value, it regained -1.

Comment: How does value relates to the database on this line?     

    const value = this.state.selectedOption2.value;   

Don't you maybe have to use pkp.id.indexOf({value}) or something similar?

Comment: i add some picture of my firebase database in order to make you clear. please focus on `const index = pkp.indexOf({ value });` At componentDidMount i import the database then put it in pkp state `this.setState({pkp})` . So `this.state.pkp` the database itself.

Comment: the question is how i get the index of my database, which i want to put in `ref()`

Comment: the result i want, when `const value = this.state.selectedOption2.value;` changed, the `ref()` will be `ref("/0"), then when `const value = this.state.selectedOption2.value;` changed for the second time, the `ref()` will be `ref("/1"), and so on.

Comment: So, indexOf searches for a value, but you are searching for this value on the whole object, you need to specify where exactly you want to search for this value.

Comment: you're not solving my problem..